# Correct HTTP status code for denying a user to evaluate a product twice?

Tags: rest, http

What HTTP status code would be suitable for this purpose? The scenario is "I cannot let you evaluate a product because you have already done it". I was thinking about forbidden 403. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `402 Payment Required`. Even though it's not widely used, I feel like it's perfect for this use case.

> **402 Payment Required**
>   Reserved for future use. The original intention was that this code might be used as part of some form of digital cash or micropayment scheme, as proposed, for example, by GNU Taler, but that has not yet happened, and this code is not usually used. Google Developers API uses this status if a particular developer has exceeded the daily limit on requests. Sipgate uses this code if an account does not have sufficient funds to start a call. Shopify uses this code when the store has not paid their fees and is temporarily disabled. Stripe uses this code for failed payments where parameters were correct, for example blocked fraudulent payments.
>   [**Source**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Answer (score -1):

use 405 Method Not Allowed - Meaning - The request method is known by the server but has been disabled and cannot be used. For example, an API may forbid DELETE-ing a resource. The two mandatory methods, GET and HEAD, must never be disabled and should not return this error code .